# Scheduled task doens't show up in task scheduler in Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule a task in Windows 7 using C++. I use the example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/taskschd/time-trigger-example--c--- . (just exchenged _wgetenv). My code looks like this:

```
/********************************************************************
 This sample schedules a task to start notepad.exe 1 minute from the
 time the task is registered.
********************************************************************/

#define _WIN32_DCOM

#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <wincred.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
//  Include the task header file.
#include <taskschd.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "taskschd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "comsupp.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "credui.lib")

using namespace std;


int __cdecl wmain()
{
    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeEx failed: %x", hr);
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set general COM security levels.
    hr = CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL,
        -1,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_PKT_PRIVACY,
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
        NULL,
        0,
        NULL);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCoInitializeSecurity failed: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create a name for the task.
    LPCWSTR wszTaskName = L"Time Trigger Test Task";

    //  Get the windows directory and set the path to notepad.exe.
    //wstring wstrExecutablePath = _wgetenv(L"WINDIR");

    // changed compared with the example
    wstring fullpath = L"WINDIR";
    wchar_t *wchar_tpExecutablePath;
    size_t len;
    errno_t err =_wdupenv_s(&wchar_tpExecutablePath, &len, &fullpath[0]);
    if (err) {
        std::cout << "Failed to resolve WINDIR" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    std::wstring wstrExecutablePath(wchar_tpExecutablePath);

    wstrExecutablePath += L"\\SYSTEM32\\NOTEPAD.EXE";
    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create an instance of the Task Service. 
    ITaskService *pService = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskScheduler,
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_ITaskService,
        (void**)&pService);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to create an instance of ITaskService: %x", hr);
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Connect to the task service.
    hr = pService->Connect(_variant_t(), _variant_t(),
        _variant_t(), _variant_t());
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("ITaskService::Connect failed: %x", hr);
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the pointer to the root task folder.  This folder will hold the
    //  new task that is registered.
    ITaskFolder *pRootFolder = NULL;
    hr = pService->GetFolder(_bstr_t(L"\\"), &pRootFolder);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Cannot get Root folder pointer: %x", hr);
        pService->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  If the same task exists, remove it.
    pRootFolder->DeleteTask(_bstr_t(wszTaskName), 0);

    //  Create the task definition object to create the task.
    ITaskDefinition *pTask = NULL;
    hr = pService->NewTask(0, &pTask);

    pService->Release();  // COM clean up.  Pointer is no longer used.
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("Failed to CoCreate an instance of the TaskService class: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the registration info for setting the identification.
    IRegistrationInfo *pRegInfo = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_RegistrationInfo(&pRegInfo);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get identification pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pRegInfo->put_Author(_bstr_t(L"Author Name"));
    pRegInfo->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put identification info: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create the principal for the task - these credentials
    //  are overwritten with the credentials passed to RegisterTaskDefinition
    IPrincipal *pPrincipal = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Principal(&pPrincipal);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get principal pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set up principal logon type to interactive logon
    hr = pPrincipal->put_LogonType(TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN);
    pPrincipal->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put principal info: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Create the settings for the task
    ITaskSettings *pSettings = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Settings(&pSettings);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get settings pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set setting values for the task.  
    hr = pSettings->put_StartWhenAvailable(VARIANT_TRUE);
    pSettings->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put setting information: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    // Set the idle settings for the task.
    IIdleSettings *pIdleSettings = NULL;
    hr = pSettings->get_IdleSettings(&pIdleSettings);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get idle setting information: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pIdleSettings->put_WaitTimeout(_bstr_t(L"PT5M"));
    pIdleSettings->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put idle setting information: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }


    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Get the trigger collection to insert the time trigger.
    ITriggerCollection *pTriggerCollection = NULL;
    hr = pTask->get_Triggers(&pTriggerCollection);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get trigger collection: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Add the time trigger to the task.
    ITrigger *pTrigger = NULL;
    hr = pTriggerCollection->Create(TASK_TRIGGER_TIME, &pTrigger);
    pTriggerCollection->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot create trigger: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    ITimeTrigger *pTimeTrigger = NULL;
    hr = pTrigger->QueryInterface(
        IID_ITimeTrigger, (void**)&pTimeTrigger);
    pTrigger->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nQueryInterface call failed for ITimeTrigger: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_Id(_bstr_t(L"Trigger1"));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        printf("\nCannot put trigger ID: %x", hr);

    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_EndBoundary(_bstr_t(L"2018-12-09T08:41:00"));
    if (FAILED(hr))
        printf("\nCannot put end boundary on trigger: %x", hr);

    //  Set the task to start at a certain time. The time 
    //  format should be YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS(+-)(timezone).
    //  For example, the start boundary below
    //  is January 1st 2005 at 12:05
    hr = pTimeTrigger->put_StartBoundary(_bstr_t(L"2018-12-09T08:41:00"));
    pTimeTrigger->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot add start boundary to trigger: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }


    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Add an action to the task. This task will execute notepad.exe.     
    IActionCollection *pActionCollection = NULL;

    //  Get the task action collection pointer.
    hr = pTask->get_Actions(&pActionCollection);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot get Task collection pointer: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Create the action, specifying that it is an executable action.
    IAction *pAction = NULL;
    hr = pActionCollection->Create(TASK_ACTION_EXEC, &pAction);
    pActionCollection->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot create the action: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    IExecAction *pExecAction = NULL;
    //  QI for the executable task pointer.
    hr = pAction->QueryInterface(
        IID_IExecAction, (void**)&pExecAction);
    pAction->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nQueryInterface call failed for IExecAction: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  Set the path of the executable to notepad.exe.
    hr = pExecAction->put_Path(_bstr_t(wstrExecutablePath.c_str()));
    pExecAction->Release();
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nCannot put action path: %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    //  ------------------------------------------------------
    //  Save the task in the root folder.
    IRegisteredTask *pRegisteredTask = NULL;
    hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(
        _bstr_t(wszTaskName),
        pTask,
        TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE,
        _variant_t(),
        _variant_t(),
        TASK_LOGON_INTERACTIVE_TOKEN,
        _variant_t(L""),
        &pRegisteredTask);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("\nError saving the Task : %x", hr);
        pRootFolder->Release();
        pTask->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\n Success! Task successfully registered. ");

    //  Clean up.
    pRootFolder->Release();
    pTask->Release();
    pRegisteredTask->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

However, the task does not show up in task scheduler, although I executed the program with admin rights. Can anybody help?

Comment: Time to review [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), retake [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and reread about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [***Minimal***, Complete, and Verifiable  Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok, so I did ask  a very specific question and provided the code because I made changes compare to the source (which I also linked to) so that people can compile the code and see where the problem is. If I hadn't provided the code I would most probably been asked why I didn't provide it. Admittedly, the code is not smal, but I have seen longer examples on SO

Comment: So, does the code actually run successful or does it output any error? BTW, I have no problems with the lengthyness of the code sample, although it could be written considerably shorter (and less brittle) by applying best practices like [RAII](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

Comment: Did you try running a program that doesn't require any access to the GUI? Also, did you run the task scheduler UI as the same user as you used to create a task? If not, I wouldn't be surprised for the task to not be shown.

Comment: The code doesn't output any errors. It runs technically speaking successfully. But the hint form Ulrich nailed it. It was really that the task scheduler being run  with administrator rights showed it. The reason I ran the program as  Admin is that it outputted an error otherwise. So it seemed quite sensible to me that it had to be run with admin priviliges in order to work at all. Thank you, all guys, and sorry for the ugly code

Comment: Now I only have to solve the problem how to schedule the task to run with the credentials of the currently logged on user and prompt the user for the password since my final goal is to write an repalcement for schtasks.exe for my purposes, but that's another story...again thank you all